# Css relative positioning

Tags: css

I am using a designer for developing U.I and this designer generating absolute positioned css for components.When some components not rendered  i want next ones positions themselves accordingly .How can i do this  with css .For example:

**I want when label3 removed from document  `<div id="div1">`  move upward and use removed label space.**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#set
{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:100px;
height:100px;
width:300px;
}

#div1{
position:relative;


}

#label1{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:30px;
height:10px;
width:10px
}

#label2{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:30px;
height:10px;
width:10px
}


#label3{
position:absolute;
left:20px;

}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<fieldset id="set">
<label id="label3">Male:</label>
<div id="div1">
<label  id="label1">Divlabel1:</label>
<label  id="label2">Divlabel2:</label>

</div>

</fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to use absolute positioning on every DOM element, because you are fixed to one resolution, and that is not what you want. As j08691 said, some code would be useful, but you might consider to learn css and html and write the UI by yourself.

Comment: CSS is complicated, you'll probably have to rethink everything. [This](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/) might help you understand how positioning works.

Comment: Let me Give example: There is two label  i want if upper one not rendered lower one position repositioned to upper one location.I want change absolute positioned css with another but i dont know how to do it with css

Comment: So what have you done so far?  Where is your code?  _"The SO community will not write a complete solution for you, develop a complete walk through of a problem, or do your background research for you, unless your question is specific and focused on a reasonably small scope"_ ~ [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157574).   [**Please read this and edit your question accordingly**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157574).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put dynamic part part of page a staticly positioned div .And change position:absolute to position:relative and remove top and left properties.Staticly positioned element are removed from document but relatively positioned ones are placed one after another.